# What types go well together in a Pokémon deck?

Tags: pokemon

Which types combine well with water types in Pokémon? I have water types, so I need to know which types go well with them so I can make a good deck.

Comment: To close voters, how is this question any different than [What is a good Pokémon deck ratio?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/3431/3389), which the community has considered to be on-topic and not opinion-based?

Comment: @Thunderforge, That other question should have been closed for being one that solicits endless opinions. (No opinion on this one since I don't know anything about the Pokemon CG. It's possible there's an answer such as "X and Y will cover most of the Pokemons to which Water types are weak". Or maybe it's clearly opinion based or too broad.)

Comment: @ikegami There are similar questions for Magic too (e.g. [How should I determine how many lands of each different color to put in my deck?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/6186/3389)). While questions of this sort may appear at first to be opinions, I think they're asking about aspects of deck consistency, which is an important part of strategy in CCGs (and I think that's on topic).

Comment: @Thunderforge I think the main difference between this and your examples, is the amount of research/effort put in by OP. Those questions show the OP's thought process and how they came to the question a bit more. I don't think that the root question here is off-topic, but I think it would be greatly improved if the OP included a bit about what they have tried so far/what research they have done. I have not VTC as I would like to see if OP makes and edits

Comment: @Thunderforge, In MTG, there is a rough agreement on how much land is needed --and perhaps even empirical data from tournaments?-- and on the factors that might cause one to vary from the default

Comment: @ikegami Those who play Pokémon competitively also have a rough agreement on these sorts of things, and there is certainly empirical data from tournaments, so I would think that any such arguments for Magic would also apply for Pokémon.

Comment: Really it depends on what pokemon you are running in your deck

Comment: @Thunderforge, Again, I don't know anything about the Pokemon card game, but the question to which you linked contradicts your claim

Answer (score 5):

### Check out the World Champion Decks to see which type synergies the top-ranked players are using

[World Champion Decks](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/World_Championships_Deck_(TCG)) have been released since 2004 and contain non-tournament-legal cards matching the decks of several high-ranking players in the [Pokémon World Championships](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/World_Championships).

Regarding Water types specifically, the only Water decks released between 2004 and 2017 were:

- Pure-Water decks (x7)
- Water/Electric decks (x4)

Therefore, I think it's fair to say that Water and Electric go well together, possibly better than others.

### Check out which type synergies are used in Theme Decks

You might also check out other [Theme Decks](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Theme_Deck_(TCG)) that have been released to see other combinations that might go together. There isn't any guarantee that they'll be good, but presumably the deck synergies that are released will be functional, and types that work well together will probably get multiple releases.

For instance, there have been more Water/Electric and Water/Psychic decks released that Water/Fighting decks, and no Water/Darkness or Water/Fairy decks. Therefore, I'd infer that the former are probably more likely to go well together than the latter, since the Pokémon Company keeps producing decks with those synergies.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than focus on *types*, the focus is generally on what your deck's archetype is.

The deck archetype is basically the main "goal" of the deck - if everything goes well, how are you going to be doing your damage and knocking out opponent's Pokémon?

Typically when constructing a deck, you have one Pokémon line or a few related Pokémon that are the "archetype".  Then you have some "tech" Pokémon who exist for their ability and/or for some other purpose (they probably won't ever attack, and might not have the right kind of energy to attack), and you have some ancillary Pokémon that you use to support your archetype if it's not working well.

This is where Type synergy could come in: if you have, for example, a Metagross deck, you're weak to Fire, so you want to have (say) Ultra Necrozma, which is Dragon, as an ancillary attacker who can step in if the opponent is running a Volcanion (fire) deck.

You also could consider certain types as ancillary attackers who are super effective against particularly common Pokémon that you run into and have trouble handling (say, a Fighting Pokémon or two to handle Zoroark, or a Psychic to handle Buzzwole).

In general, though, you won't find all that many decks that actually run two energy types as co-equals, among strong decks.  It's too important to have a single strong archetype most of the time.

Comment: And just to reinforce the idea, in looking at the top decks, you almost always see they only have the one type of energy card for their archetype Pokemon combined with colorless and/or rainbow energy to enable their tech pokemon, rather than having to stock two types of energy such as in theme decks.